# Advice about GCM unregister

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application with login/logout that uses android's Accounts. I'm using GCM too, so when the user logs in I register the device and if the user logs out I unregister it. I'm facing a problem with the unregister call.

To unregister my device from my server I need the account's token. Since I can't pass it to the onUnregistered method from GCMIntentService (or at least I don't know how), I tried to get it using AccountManager, but at that point my account is already deleted. I want to solve it, and two options came to my mind:

1- Call first GCMRegistrar.unregister and delete the account in the GCMIntentService->onUnregistered function. The problem with this solution is that the user has to wait for unregister to finish, and maybe it doesn't. I can't let the user go on without deleting the account.

2- Save the token somewhere (application class maybe) to be able to get it from GCMIntentService->onUnregistered.

I think the number 2 is better, but I don't know if it's the best choice. Is there any better way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the token in the IntentService you can save it with SharedPreferences:

```
public void savePrefrences(String key, String value)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = SynergyApplication._context.getSharedPreferences(SynergyApplication._context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
        prefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }
```

And then read it from everywhere in your app:

```
public String getPrefrences(String key)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = SynergyApplication._context.getSharedPreferences(SynergyApplication._context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
        return prefs.getString(key, "");
    }
```

Comment: Seems I was right to use number 2, thank you for suggesting me to use SharedPreferences, I'll do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use onDestroy in your main activity. With that, you are sure to call this method when the user close the app. I don't know how you are deleting the device from your server (with an url?).

The onDestroy method guarantee that your code will be executed when the user closes the app.